# What is the performance of checking an attribute vs checking a return value of a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance, angular8

I have a list of items in a component:

```
list: Array<MyType>;
```

The user can select and deselect elements on click:

```
toggleItem(item: MyType) {
  if (this.selection.has(item)) {
    this.selection.delete(item);
    return;
  }

  this.selection.add(item);
}
```

The selected items are stored in a `Set`:

```
selected: Set<MyType> = new Set();
```

Now I need to toggle a CSS class and a `title`-attribute depending whether an element is selected or not:

```
<button class="toggle"
        type="button"
        [ngClass]="{'selected': selection.has(item)}"
        [title]="selection.has(item) ? 'Select' : 'Deselect'"
        (click)="toggleItem(item)">
  {{ item.title }}
</button>
```

---

Now I've read somewhere that it is a bad idea, to evaluate function calls as Angular periodically will call them for change detection, like here:

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': selection.has(item)}"
```

They say that it's better to check a variable or a member of the object instead, like:

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': item.selected}"
```

Is is true and does it decrease performance the way I use it currently? Should I add a property to each item that is set when it's added to or removed from the `Set`?

Comment: What happens when you run a benchmark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever Angular performs change detection, it checks whether anything that's *variable* and is in the template has changed.

Now, the check is pretty straight forward in case of model variables as Angular can simply read values of them in order to check for a change.

But that's not really the case with a function. With functions, Angular can only determine if the variable has changed by calling the function itself.

Now it doesn't make much of a difference if the function is a one-liner return of a value.

But in case the function has complex logic, it will essentially kill all the performance. As every time the change detection cycle runs, Angular will call that function in order to check for changes and detect them.

Hence, it's not really recommended to write functions in data-binding syntax in templates.

> NOTE: I've also written a [**Medium Article**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db) about this. I'd suggest you check it out. It's mainly about Angular Reactive Forms performance. But it will help you better understand what I said above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes sense. Also thanks for the link with a deeper explanation of things. So in general it depends, and a simple internal function like `Set.has()´ or a simple return of a boolean is fine, but everything more complex should be avoided.

Comment: Yes. But again, as far as possible, try keeping your Component class, less polluted with functions if you can use class properties instead.